# Remote connection of Jboss 7 server fails with Proxy exception

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, ejb, jboss7.x

I have a Jboss 7 server running & accepting secure connections on port 443.

All along i was testing locally which was working fine . However now when i make connection attempts i get a

"`javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to create proxy [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ...`" .

I tried to follow what is written @ [EJB invocations from a remote client using JNDI](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI)

I guess my jndi.properties & jboss-ejb-client.properties file need changes . I think i got it right but still no success .

1 ) jndi.properties

```
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.ejb.client.naming
```

2 ) jboss-ejb-client.properties

```
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false

remote.connections=default

remote.connection.default.host=10.160.148.61
remote.connection.default.port = 4447
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
```

Any suggestions anyone . Making the port 443 also doesnt help .

My ejb call from the client

```
    InitialContext aJNDI = new InitialContext();
    Ppi handle = (Ppi) aJNDI
            .lookup("ejb:PPIEAR/PService/PConnect!com.gem.p.PConnection?stateful");
```

Posting Full stracktrace :

```
log4j: Finished configuring.
- JBoss EJB Client version 1.0.5.Final
- XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
- XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
- JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
- Could not register a EJB receiver for connection to remote://10.160.148.61:4447
java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.IoFutureHelper.get(IoFutureHelper.java:93)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.setupEJBReceivers(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:121)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.<init>(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:78)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.<clinit>(EJBClientContext.java:77)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClient.createSession(EJBClient.java:160)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.naming.ejb.EjbNamingContext.doCreateProxy(EjbNamingContext.java:135)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.naming.ejb.EjbNamingContext.createEjbProxy(EjbNamingContext.java:113)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.naming.ejb.EjbNamingContext.lookup(EjbNamingContext.java:96)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
..
```

Comment: also, have you verified `ejb:PPIEAR/PService/PConnect!com.gem.p.PConnection?stateful` actually exists in your target JNDI namespace?

Comment: @eis how to check that the namespace is correct . Well if i use local server meaning i change ``remote.connection.default.host=localhost`` and run the application locally then the application runs correctly . I have deployed the same ear on the remote server . so i was guess this invocation is correct ..

Comment: ok, then you probably have either a wrong combination of ip + port, server not listening or a firewall preventing the connection. I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [this page](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-as-7/jboss-as-7-remote-ejb-client-tutorial/page-2):

> WARN: Could not register a EJB receiver for connection to
>   remote://10.160.148.61:4447 java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed
>   with status WAITING

This is commonly caused by a wrong combination of IP or port in the file jboss-ejb-client.properties.

- You might be unable to reach that host address
- Maybe you are using a port-offset on that server, so instead of port 4447 you should use 4447 + offset

---

You could start by testing if you can connect to your target using telnet:

```
telnet 10.160.148.61 4447
```

Comment: well i did come across this . I dont see how my IP port may be wrong , because the IP is pingable from my system & looking at the standalone.xml file on the server the remoting port is indeed 4447 .     ''    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="80"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="443"/>
        <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
        <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/> ''  . I still wonder what is wrong

Comment: btw i have done nothing on the server side . Do you think something needs to be done on the server to allow it to accept all incoming connections .. I am trying to follow that lead as well with no success :(

Comment: Ok i finally was able to resolve this problem . Indeed it was a problem commmunicating to the server . I had to enable to firewall on the server to allow connections on the port 4447 . Great help thanks !

Comment: Now however i get a different exception related to security but then that is because i need to connect to a server which has a SSL certificate installed . Phew Phew ... :( :(

Comment: @rockstar ping only tells if ping port is open and answering, and remote desktop will tell if remote desktop ports are open. When testing for connectivity for a specific port, you should use telnet to connect to the port you're after, so something like `telnet 192.168.1.1 4447`.

Comment: You were correct here ;-) Port 4447 was not open on that the server system . I enabled that port and now it works fine . I appreciate your help :-)